# Prestashop Hooks in module [Prestashop 1.5.6.2]

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I created a new module as follows.

```
<?php

class dpmessages extends Module
{

function __construct()
{
    $this->name = 'dpmessages';
    $this->tab = 'administration';
    $this->version = '0.1';

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('DP messages');
    $this->description = $this->l('Envoyer messages');

    parent::__construct();
    /* The parent construct is required for translations */
}

function install()
{
    $this->registerHook('actionAuthentication');
    if (parent::install() == FALSE
    )
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;

}

function uninstall()
{
    if (!parent::uninstall())
        return false;
    return true;
}


public function hookActionAuthentication($params) {
    echo "<pre>".print_r($params)."</pre>";die();
}

}
```

I registered a hook of actionAuthentication on it which I presume will fire the code of hookActionAuthentication each time a new user logs in but it isn't firing.

I can't see the dump of $params.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check your Prestashop database for `ps_module`, `ps_hook`, and `ps_hook_module` tables. If your module is installed and has the hook correctly registered you will find a row in `ps_hook_module` table with your module and hook id. Then you will know if it is hook registration or hook calling problem. Post your results.

Answer (score 0):

You should first call parent::install(); and only then registerHook function.

You can always check whether the module is hooked to the right hook in Modules -> Positions